# chrome.webRequest is not available

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm facing this issue when I try to run `chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived`.

Here is my code:

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "testing",
"description": "testing",
"version": "1.0",

"permissions":
[
    "webRequest","*://*/*","webRequestBlocking"
],

"content_scripts":
[
    {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "css": ["highlight.css"],
        "js": ["highlight.js","jquery-min.js" ],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames": true
    }
]}
```

highlight.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
function(info) {
    var headers = info.responseHeaders;
    for (var i=headers.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
        var header = headers[i].name.toLowerCase();
        if (header == 'x-frame-options' || header == 'frame-options') {
            headers.splice(i, 1); // Remove header
        }
    }
    return {responseHeaders: headers};
},
{
    urls: [ '*://*/*' ], // Pattern to match all http(s) pages
    types: [ 'sub_frame' ]
},
['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
);
```

When I run the script, I get errors as below:

> chrome.webRequest is not available: You do not have permission to access this API. Ensure that the required permission or manifest property is included in your manifest.json.
>       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onHeadersReceived' of undefined

Any idea on this? I tried to apply solutions in previous post but not working.

Comment: You have to use a [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) or [event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) page.

Comment: did you means that need to put chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener into background page?

Comment: Yes. The APIs exposed to [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) is limited.